# pass arguments to sql.squish

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I want to use `EXIST` in my select request for having a "published" column depending of if the article was published in a book in a set of year.

So I do the following

```rb
 p params[:years]               # "2002"
 p params[:years].is_a?(String) # true

 Article.select(<<~SQL.squish, years: params[:years])
    articles.*, EXISTS(
      SELECT 1
      FROM books
      WHERE books.year IN (:years)
    ) AS published
    SQL
```

But it gives me the follwing error

> Unsupported argument type: Hash. Construct an Arel node instead

and if I try like this

```rb
 p params[:years]               # "2002"
 p params[:years].is_a?(String) # true

 Article.select(<<~SQL.squish)
    articles.*, EXISTS(
      SELECT 1
      FROM books
      WHERE books.year IN (#{params[:years]})
    ) AS published
    SQL
```

> PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = bigint
> WHERE books.year IN (2022)

But params[:years] is a string I don't know how I can do what I want and I don't understand both of errors.

EDIT: if I use single quote like this

```rb
 p params[:years]               # "2002"
 p params[:years].is_a?(String) # true

 Article.select(<<~SQL.squish)
    articles.*, EXISTS(
      SELECT 1
      FROM books
      WHERE books.year IN ('#{params[:years]}')
    ) AS published
    SQL
```

It work for a single value but if params[:years] is an array it work but the output isn't correct, if I have articles in a book in 2003 it will set published at false

```rb
 p params[:years]               # ["2002", "2003"]
 p params[:years].is_a?(String) # false
 Article.select(<<~SQL.squish)
    articles.*, EXISTS(
      SELECT 1
      FROM books
      WHERE books.year IN ('#{params[:years]}')
    ) AS published
    SQL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By interpolating the user input into a SQL query you're leaving yourself wide open for an [SQL injection attack](https://bobby-tables.com/).

This is easy to prevent by using Arel to construct the query instead:

```
Article.select(
  Article.arel_table[Arel.star],
  Book.select(1)
      .where(year: params[:years])  
      .arel
      .exists
      .as('published')
)
```

```
SELECT 
  "articles".*, 
  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM "books" WHERE "books"."year" IN (?, ?, ?)) AS published 
FROM "articles"
```

Comment: The second part of the question is really WHY params[:years] is a string and not an array.

Comment: If I have only one year it could be a string, couldn't it ? array for multiple values, and string for one value. Also thank you it work

Answer (score 2):

The `Object.select` method in ActiveRecord doesn't support sanitised insertion of placeholders in the way that, for example, `.where` does. And that's why you're getting the error you're getting – `select` is expecting a list of fields, but one of your arguments is a Hash.

One way to get the functionality you're looking for is, as the error message suggests, to use Arel (if you're not familiar with it, think of Arel as the "building blocks" that ActiveRecord uses internally to construct its SQL queries). [Max's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67691940/1326518) is a good translation of your query into Arel.

Alternatively, you can sanitize your own SQL in the same way that other parts of ActiveRecord do. Splitting this up into the SQL parsing and the select statement for clarity:

```rb
sql = Article.sanitize_sql([<<~SQL, year: params[:years]])
  articles.*, EXISTS(
      SELECT 1
      FROM books
      WHERE books.year IN (:years)
    ) AS published
SQL
Article.select(sql)
```

I'd say that hand sanitising your SQL will get you over the stumbling block you're currently at, but if you're going to be doing similar types of operation all over the shop you'll benefit from understanding what Arel does and how to use it.